# Switch always runs the same case statement Xcode 5

Tags: objective-c, switch-statement, xcode5

So I have a random word generator that uses a switch to randomly assign a word to a variable.
However, after some testing, I have discovered that it always  runs 'case 2' and never case 0, 1 or default.

Here's my code:

```
int randWord1 = rand() % 2;
switch (randWord1) {
    case 0:
        mainTextView.text = @"1";


    case 1:
        mainTextView.text = @"2";


    case 2:
        mainTextView.text = @"3";

    break;

    default:
    break;
}
```

**Edit:**

After having the question closed for typos in the code, I discovered that the issue was that I had forgotten to add a `break;` statement after each `case X:` statement.

Comment: Please update your tags with tags that are actually relevant (such as the language being used).

Comment: This may work ok for 3 cases, but it's not a good approach for a longer list. Instead, you should put the words into an array, and pass the random number to objectAtIndex: to get a random word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is what you are missing:

```
Case 0 {
mainTextView.text = @"1";
break;
}

Case 1 {
mainTextView.text = @"2";
break;
}

Case 2 {
mainTextView.text = @"3";
break;
}
Default:
```

Notice the `break` in each `Case x`.

In `C`, each case will execute if you don't put proper `break` statements before the next `Case`. In your situation, since `Case 2` is the last case with any executable statements in it, you will always see `mainTextView.text` being set to `3`. If, for sake of argument you had

```
Default: {
mainTextView.text = @"foo";
break;
}
```

you would have seen `foo` printed every time because there was no `break` after `Case 2:`

Comment: Oh! Thanks, I thought breaks went outside the brackets

Comment: that should not matter as long as they are present in the executable scope of the case

Comment: Do I HAVE to put the `{}` after each case statement?

Comment: that is not required as far as i know but helpful for readability.

Answer (score 1):

You have to break after each case, even though it seems counterintuitive/unnecessary.

Comment: I think I may have done that... But just to clarify is breaking when you go   break: ?

Comment: Yes, correct.  After each case executes its logic, a break; before the next case guarantees an exit from the switch.

Comment: Yes, but why does it always run case 2?!

Comment: There is a quirk of C in which a switch will continue running all case statements if there is not a break.  So whether the case is 0, 1 or 2, it will always run through to 2, and thus set that result.  This is exploited by a trick called Duff's Device, actually. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device